# Is there a way to know what areas are appropriate for certain levels?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

In Lord of the Rings Online, is there a way to know which areas are appropriate for certain levels?

My friends and I have been playing the game for a while now and following the Epic Book quest lines starting in Bree, and are now to book 3, however we are just barely high enough level to get the quests in the areas we are at, and the guys we fight just destroy us if there are more than like 2 of them.

Where should characters in their high 20's to low 30's be questing?  We've wandered back towards the Shire, but all the quests there are for levels 10 or lower, and are barely worth doing.

Help?

Comment: Short: Evendim/Trollshaws/East Lone-Lands

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- 1 to 5

Starting Area (depends on your race)

- 5 to 10

The Shire, Ered Luin, or Combe.

- 10 to 15

Bree-land quests, such as Chief Watcher Grimbiar's (exit out of Bree-Town through the west-gate and then go north) cabin. This will lead you down to Andrath, where you can get some quests, too.

- 15 to 20

Adso's Camp, The Barrow-Downs, and the Northern Bree-fields. There is a camp where you can get some "bounty" quests, which can be done three times each to get Sapphire Shards and rare single-use crafting recipes.

- 20 to 25

The Lone-Lands and Trestlebridge. Finding quests in the Lone-Lands can be not very obvious. The quest hubs are at The Foresaken Inn, Canadiath's Encampment, and a dwarf outside the mine.

Also for this leveling range, do some skirmishes and Great Barrow runs for the Barrow-Scholar/Scout/Warrior set. It will last you until Evendim

- 25 to 30

The North Downs, Ost Guruth,  Harloeg (the bog south of Ost Guruth), and Evendim

At this level you can go to the dwarf-camp (north of Estedlin), the elf-refuge (south of Estedlin), Estedlin, or Ost Guruth. You can also head to Evendim, I like Evendim because you can get Wardens of Annuminas reputation. At kindred, you can get teal-quality weapons. Additionally, questing in Evendim will get you an armor set that is fairly good.

You can also begin on the Trollshaws

- 30 to 35

Ost Forod or Trollshaws. Start at Barachad's Camp, but if you've already outleveled those, head to Elrohir/Elladan's Camp.

- 35 to 40

Rivendell and Tal Bruinen. While Rivendell doesn't have many quests, Tal Bruinen has enough to get you to 40. Additionally you can get Armor of the Woods, another good 3-piece armor set, while questing in Tal Bruinen.

- 40 to 45

Forochel, West Angmar, or the Misty Mountans.

If you, at this point, do not have access to a tailor/metalsmith to make you some armor, you will need to go to West Angmar to get you the Fem set. There will be many quests on your quest to get all of the Fem pieces, but at the end you will get a teal-quality pocket item.

While questing in Forochel, you will get a 3-piece teal-quality jewelry set. You will also get Forochel rep which you need for frost-resistance armor

- 45 to 50

Forochel, East Angmar, Eregion, and the Walls of Moria

As soon as you hit 45 run aallll the way down to the Walls of Moria (in south Eregion) to grab your legendary item. Don't worry, the level 50 quests are easily doable at level 45, because all of the mobs are Swarm. When you get you first legendary item, you'll get a quest to get it to level 10. This will take you some time, so go quest somewhere else in the mean time.

East Angmar is very difficult to navigate. There are many grouping quests there, so if you are solo'ing don't go there.

You will also have some more places to go in Forochel. Suri-kyla is another good quest hub.

Eregion is my favorite place here. The quest chains flow very nicely. Once you are at ~50 you will be able to

> accept a quest from the many Explorer's of Eregion you probably were seeing
>  all this time

- 50 to 55

Moria (and all zones inside it)

Some people hate Moria, some people love it. While getting around is very difficult, it is very fun and the quest rewards are good quality. The revamp of Moria has brightened it up, and made the quest flow better.

Additionally, Moria is no place for a horse! Make sure you have a goat, such as the one you can get from getting Kindred with Thorin's Hall. If you don't have one, that's fine, as you can get one for free that goes half speed from a quest in the intial area.

- 55 to 60

Lothlorien and the Dimrill Dale

You don't have to do the Dimrill Dale quests but you can if you want

Lothlorien is my favorite region. It looks very nice and the quests are very easy.

The update removed the machine bow elves, meaning that you no longer need Acquaintence standing to enter. If you want to kill things, go to the orc encampment to the west of Caras Gladhron.

Many of the quests here are "pick 10 flowers." No, seriously.

Additionally make sure you do all your daily quests daily, as they are often very easy.

The main city of this region is Caras Gladhron. It requires Friend standing to enter and has many easy quests, as well as the Instance quests (kill 25 orcs inside a moria instance) and the Battle for Lothlorien (it's like a skirmish but can only be done at fellowship difficulty)

You can also get nice cosmetics and jewlerry

- 60 to 65

Mirkwood or Enedwaith

I really hate Mirkwood. The quests are difficult to find, and it's too dark. Like Angmar, but with trees. The enemies and quests are (mostly) difficult too. Additionally, the reputation rewards are bad.

Enedwaith is the opposite of Mirkwood. The quests are very easy.

> There is also a hobbit (!!!) village in Enedwaith, it's in the Red region at the top

You can also get Grey Company rep and Algraig rep. These can be used to get new emotes like /sneeze and /spin. There is teal-quality cloaks and necklace at kindred level.

- 65 to 70

Dunland

Dunland is very simple to understand. The quests go in a counterclockwise circle, from the top left to the Rohan Scout-Camp. There are some really good instances, such as "Tusks of the Boar."

- 70 to 75

The Gap of Rohan, Isengard (Nan Curinir), and The Great River

At this point you can go south of the Rohan-Scout Camp and find some Rohhric Camps. These have lots of quests, and then when you are done here, if you are still not 75, then go to Isengard, which is north of Grimbold's Camp.

When you are at level 75, go back to Galtrev and go near the Auction Hall.  There will be a guy named Mabon and his father. Doing these quests will teleport you to the Ox-Clan Merchant Camp, which will leave you ready to do the Tower of Orthanc and the Isengard Instance Cluster.

Also, make sure you get the quest from the White-hand guard from the south-gate. These will start a quest chain that will leave you ready to do Draigoch.

As for the Great River...you have Limlight Gorge rep to get for the teal-quality jewelry set.

- 75 to 80

Start off by heading to Lothlorien and the House of Celebrant. You should have gotten a mail at level 75 asking you to do this. This will start you on an epic quest to go to Rohan. I recommend doing these first as otherwise you will do a lot of traveling.

Follow the epic quests and the

- Epics

The epic quest line gives very good rewards and generally will show you which areas to quest in.

Completing volume one will give you a teal weapon and a title. (ALL of it! Up to book 15)
Completing Volume Two will unlock the Epilogue for it, one of which will give you

> Cucheron's Bow (because he died)

Completing Volume Three...is not currently possible, although completing book six will give you a Worn Symbol of Celembrior, which will allow you get a second age Legendary Item.

Comment: Wow one hour to write an answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is some info:

Bree\Ered Luin\Shire lvl 0-~20
North Downs\Lonelands lvl 20-30
Evendim\Trollshaws lvl 30-40
Angmar\Forochel lvl 40-50
Eregion 48-52
Moria 50-60
Lothlorien 55-60
Mirkwood\Enedwaith lvl 60-~65
Isengard 65-75
Great River lvl 70-75

All these levels are available if you're doing all deeds, and all quests, and can vary depends on how are you playing. But best idea is to combine zones, like do some quests here, and move there. You'll get benefits of farming quest deeds -> traits.